# How to Monitor redis using application rest endpoint?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis

My requirement is to get redis stats using application rest end points.
I dont want to use Redis cli .
Is there any way to do it? or are there any API which provide redis stats?

I am using spring boot with redis